# Using google maps routing user interface with Bing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bing-maps

I like to use google map in a web application as the background map, and I would like to call the routing service api for bing maps with javascript.
But I love the google map routing user interface.
is it possible even to hook the user interface of google map routing to call routing/geocoding from bing map service?

Answer (score 1):

Mixing the two platforms is against the terms of use of both platforms.

Comment: Thanks.
It is just for a demo I am doing to the customers exploring the features in bing maps api, in case they incorporate it in their application.
It is not a real application.

Comment: Even for demo purposes, it cannot be done as Ricky said.